# Why map convas is not appearing in Slide in Ionic 2

Tags: dictionary, ionic2

In this code I want to load `map` on second slide but in second `Slide` map `convas` is not appearing

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{Origin}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label> {{Target}} </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-40>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{name}} </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-50>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label> :{{tel}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-70>
      <button ion-button block outline color="secondary" (click)="Getorder()" large>Get Order</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{price}} </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
  <div id="map_canvas"> </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

**in scss file**

```
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Update: in ts file**

```
initializeMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);

    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds); //# auto - zoom
    this.map.panToBounds(this.bounds); //# auto-center
    this.OriginMarker(this.start_point);
    this.TargetMarker(this.end_point);
  }
```

Comment: can you add the component side? and what exactly does it show?

Comment: Hi @Suraj i only added this line in ordermodal.ts   '@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;', firist slide is appear but second slide page is blank.

Comment: so you havent loaded the map?

Comment: I had updated question. if i remove slide related tags from HTML map will load correctly but when I move to Slide tags did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the map div through `ViewChild`.

```
<ion-slide>
  <div id="map_canvas" #map> </div>
  </ion-slide>
```

In the component side:

```
@ViewChild('map') map:ElementRef;

initializeMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.map.nativeElement, {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);

    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds); //# auto - zoom
    this.map.panToBounds(this.bounds); //# auto-center
    this.OriginMarker(this.start_point);
    this.TargetMarker(this.end_point);
  }
```

Comment: still the same.